# Javascript use find in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array data

```
var data = [
    {name:'hr', to:'/hr/settings', children:[
        {name:'Language', to:'/hr/settings/general/languages', icon:''},
        {name:'Marital Status', to:'/hr/settings/general/marital-status', icon:''},
        {name:'Nationalities', to:'/hr/settings/general/nationalities', icon:''},
        {name:'Ethnicities', to:'/hr/settings/general/ethnicities', icon:''},
        {name:'Religions', to:'/hr/settings/general/religions', icon:''},
        {name:'Tribes', to:'/hr/settings/general/tribes', icon:''},
        {name:'Relations', to:'/hr/settings/general/relations', icon:''}
    ]},
    {name:'education', to:'/hr/education', children:[
        {name:'Universities',to:'/hr/settings/education/universities', icon:''},
        {name:'Relations',to:'//hr/settings/education/relations', icon:''}
    ]}
];
```

So what am looking forward to do is find the index of the data array which has to value in it or its children similar to a certain string

so i have the following

```
function getArrayIndex(tovalue) {
    const pathnavigated = data.find(link => link.to === tovalue);
    return data.indexOf(pathnavigated);
}
```

The above works for the array eg `getArrayIndex('/hr/settings')` but now i want it to search also the children

eg

```
getArrayIndex('/hr/settings/general/marital-status')
```

should return the first index

and `getArrayIndex('/hr/settings/education/universities')`  should return the second index

How do i make the function to search even the children and return the value of the index on the parent array (of the child)

Comment: You only want the index?

Comment: yes only the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a slight modification to your function `getArrayIndex` and added the following:

```js
data.find(link => link.children.filter(b=>b.to == tovalue).length > 0)
```

In here, I filter the children and if there is at least one children that match your string, returns it.

```js
var data = [
      {name:'hr',to:'/hr/settings', children:[
                    {name:'Language',to:'/hr/settings/general/languages', icon:''},
                    {name:'Marital Status',to:'/hr/settings/general/marital-status', icon:''},
                    {name:'Nationalities',to:'/hr/settings/general/nationalities', icon:''},
                    {name:'Ethnicities',to:'/hr/settings/general/ethnicities', icon:''},
                    {name:'Religions',to:'/hr/settings/general/religions', icon:''},
                    {name:'Tribes',to:'/hr/settings/general/tribes', icon:''},
                    {name:'Relations',to:'/hr/settings/general/relations', icon:''}]},   
       {name:'education', to:'/hr/education', children:[
                    {name:'Universities',to:'/hr/settings/education/universities', icon:''},
                    {name:'Relations',to:'//hr/settings/education/relations', icon:''}]}

  ]
  
 function getArrayIndex(tovalue){
    const pathnavigated = data.find(link => link.children.filter(b=>b.to == tovalue).length > 0);
    return data.indexOf(pathnavigated);
}

console.log(getArrayIndex('/hr/settings/education/universities') )
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `some()` instead of `filter()`, so you don't have to check the length. Some returns true if any of the childern passes the check in the lambda. If you still want to search the top level items, don't forget to check for both conditions: `link.to === tovalue || link.children.some(c => c.to === tovalue)`.

```
function getArrayIndex(tovalue) {
    const pathnavigated = data.find(link =>
        link.to === tovalue || link.children.some(c => c.to === tovalue));
    return data.indexOf(pathnavigated);
}
```

Comment: I believe he wants to get the index of the children, not the top level. The description says that the first example should return first index, which I guess means `1` ..

Comment: And `getArrayIndex('/hr/settings/education/universities')` should return the second one - which would make sense if it's the top level index.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody already beat me to it.. but still..

```
function getIndex(array, search) {
    for (let i = 0;i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].to === search) {
            return i;
        }

        if (Array.isArray(array[i].children)) {
            for (let j = 0; j < array[i].children.length; j++) {
                if (array[i].children[j].to === search) {
                    return j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: what is not `neat` ?

Comment: i mean its not very refactored, eg instead of multiple for loops you coud just use .find which makes code more readable and easy to maintain